# OpenSceneGraph in Fedora

Tags: linux, openscenegraph

I install OpenSceneGraph in Fedora 22 by this commands:

```
 $ sudo dnf install OpenSceneGraph-devel  
 $ sudo dnf install OpenSceneGraph
```

but when use osgviewer or osgversion command, osg not run and this messages are shown:

```
osgviewer: error while loading shared libraries: libosgViewer.so.130: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  
osgversion: error while loading shared libraries: libosgDB.so.130: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
# dnf search OpenSceneGraph
```

... to watch all available OpenSceneGraph packages.

```
# dnf provides */libosgViewer.so.130
# dnf provides */libosgDB.so.130
```

... to decide the package providing the libraries.

```
# dnf install OpenSceneGraph-libs
```